Too few arguments to function App\Jobs\OrangeJob::__construct(), 0 passed in
when i run the laravel schedule comman, "php artisan schedule:work "i get this error. am running;
laravel 11
php 8.3

   ArgumentCountError 

  Too few arguments to function App\Jobs\OrangeJob::__construct(), 0 passed in D:\projects\pulse\routes\console.php on line 8 and exactly 1 expected

  at app\Jobs\OrangeJob.php:20
     16▕ {
     17▕     use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
     18▕     public $tries = 3;
     19▕     public  $orange;
  ➜  20▕     public function __construct( $orange )
     21▕     {
     22▕         $this->orange=$orange;
     23▕     }
     24▕

  1   routes\console.php:8
      App\Jobs\OrangeJob::__construct()
  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:499


don't know why i get that error.
here is my controller from where am dispatching the job
    public function index()
    {
        $oranges = DB::connection('connectpay')
            ->table('oranges')
            ->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))
            ->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1)->toDateTimeString())
            ->where('status', '=', 'pending')->get();

        foreach ($oranges as $orange) {
            OrangeJob::dispatch($orange);
        }
    }


my laravel's job class
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Test;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use function Laravel\Prompts\table;

class OrangeJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $tries = 3;
    public  $orange;
    public function __construct( $orange )
    {
        $this->orange=$orange;
    }

    public function handle():void
    {
    
       $orange= $this->orange;
        //        we check our transactions status
        $this->checkOrangeTransactions($orange);
    }


here is my routes/console file where i want to chedule the job
<?php

use App\Jobs\OrangeJob;



Schedule::job(new OrangeJob())->everySecond();


thank in advance

I have no idea what this is but doesn't the OrangeJob constructor require an argument?

In this please pass some arguments to OrangeJob()
Schedule::job(new OrangeJob())->everySecond();

Modified code will be like:
$someArgument = "some data or dataset";
Schedule::job(new OrangeJob($someArgument))->everySecond();


thanks a lot, this worked too, thanks fore the early reply

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as REGEX explanation and examples, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

OrangeJob is expecting parameter. when dispatching the the parameters not passing via OrangeJob.
$orange = [
   id: "ewdsdmsmd",
   user_id : 2
];

Schedule::job(new OrangeJob($orange))->everySecond();


thanks a lot, am grateful, it worked, after a long time of pudering whia i did wrong

its my pleassure
